# Problema de acentos en el nombre al momento de guardar un archivo en php

Tags: php, archivo, utf-8

tengo un problema al momento de subir archivos en php, los archivos suben bien pero quedan con el nombre: PresentaciÃ³n1.pptx cuando deberían quedar Presentación1.pptx, debido a que el nombre cambia no los puedo llamar después, he intentado con utf8_encode($_FILES["fileit"]["name"]); pero no funciona lo sigue guardando igual, ya revise el charset="utf-8" en los headers y están bien, en la base de datos si guarda los datos con los acentos pero en los archivos no.

Agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

puedes intentar

```
utf8_decode($_FILES["fileit"]["name"]);
```

Comment: Se me olvido anotar que también intente con el código que dices y no funciona, al final lo solucione implementando una función que elimina los acentos y renombra el archivo antes de subirlo al servidor. Muchas gracias.